# Functionalizing my code - calling a externally created data frame into function

Tags: r

I have a data frame called "Region_Data" which I have created by performing some functions on it.

I want to take this data frame called "Region_Data" and use it an input and I want to subset it using the following function that I created. The function should produce the subset data frame:

```
Region_Analysis_Function <- function(Input_Region){
      Subset_Region_Data = subset(Region_Data, Region == "Input_Region" )
      Subset_Region_Data
    }
```

However, when I create this function and then execute it using:

```
Region_Analysis_Fuction("North West")
```

I get 0 observations when I execute this code (though I know that there are xx number of observations in the data frame.)

I read that there is something called global / local environment, but I'm not really clear on that.

How do I solve this issue? Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Try using `Region == Input_Region` (no quotes). Or better yet, you may want to use `Region %in% Input_Region` in case a non-atomic is passed to the function.

Comment: Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) on the use of `subset`

Answer (score 3):

When you try to subset your data using `subset(Region_Data, Region == "Input_Region" )`, `"Input_Region"` is being interpreted as a string literal, rather than being evaluated to the value it represents. This means that unless the column `Input_Region` in your object `Region_Data` contains some rows with the value `"Input_Region"`, your function will return a zero-row subset. Removing the quotes will solve this, and changing `==` to `%in%` will make your function more generalized. Consider the following data set,

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = rnorm(5),
  z = letters[1:5])
##
R> mydf
  x          y z
1 1 -0.4015449 a
2 2  0.4875468 b
3 3  0.9375762 c
4 4 -0.7464501 d
5 5  0.8802209 e
```

and the following 3 functions,

```
qfoo <- function(Z) {
  subset(mydf, z == "Z")
}
foo <- function(Z) {
  subset(mydf, z == Z)
}
##
bar <- function(Z) {
  subset(mydf, z %in% Z)
}
```

where `qfoo` represents the approach used in your question, `foo` implements the first change I noted, and `bar` implements both changes.

The second two functions will work when the input value is a scalar,

```
R> qfoo("c")
[1] x y z
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
##
R> foo("c")
  x         y z
3 3 0.9375762 c
##
R> bar("c")
  x         y z
3 3 0.9375762 c
```

---

but only the third will work if it is a vector:

```
R> foo(c("a","c"))
  x          y z
1 1 -0.4015449 a
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(z, Z) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
##
R> bar(c("a","c"))
  x          y z
1 1 -0.4015449 a
3 3  0.9375762 c
```